# Efficient NumPy rows rotation over variable distances

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, optimization

Given a 2D `M x N` NumPy array and a list of rotation distances, I want to rotate all `M` rows over the distances in the list. This is what I currently have:

```py
import numpy as np

M = 6
N = 8
dists = [2,0,2,1,4,2] # for example
matrix = np.random.randint(0,2,(M,N))

for i in range(M):
    matrix[i] = np.roll(matrix[i], -dists[i])
```

The last two lines are actually part of an inner loop that gets executed hundreds of thousands of times and it is bottlenecking my performance as measured by cProfile. Is it possible to, for instance, avoid the for-loop and to do this more efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can simulate the rolling behaviour with modulus operation after adding `dists` with a `range(0...N)` array to give us column indices for each row from where elements are to be picked and shuffled in the same row. We can vectorize this process across all rows with the help of [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html). Thus, we would have an implementation like so -

```
M,N = matrix.shape # Store matrix shape

# Get column indices for all elems for a rolled version with modulus operation
col_idx = np.mod(np.arange(N) + dists[:,None],N)

# Index into matrix with ranged row indices and col indices to get final o/p
out = matrix[np.arange(M)[:,None],col_idx]
```

Comment: While this is almost 65% faster when I test just these lines with the `timeit` module, when I throw it in the total code it makes it actually 20% _slower_ (averaging over multiple runs, not so high standard deviation). Any guesses why that could be the case?

Comment: @GekkeBoer What's the shape of matrix in your actual case?

Comment: I have more cases, but I was benchmarking with 4x4 just now. However, with your approach I can compute col_idx outside some loops, and then it is a lot faster! Thanks! I'll wait a bit with accepting this as the correct answer in case someone is able to improve it still.

Comment: @GekkeBoer Yes, if you are working with arrays of the same shape and `dists`, this `col_idx` should be re-usable.